# Instead of Iframe ? I want to use jquery function,iframe takes to much time to load?

Tags: jquery, iframe

Instead of  Iframe ? I want to use onload function and trigger function in jquery  using div tag or anhor tag,because iframe takes to much times to load.

**Here is the existing code: I don't want to use iframe ,instead of iframe shall i user jquery?**

```
<iframe width="560" height="315"
 src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/701pwm78Q90" 
 frameborder="0" 
 allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

The code I tried with HTML/CSS

```
<div id="te">
   <a href="https://youtu.be/701pwm78Q90">click here to see the video</a>
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="application/x-javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e){
  $("div#te").load(function(){
    $("a").trigger(click);
  });
});
</script>
```

Here is my link:
http://vkacademy.in/iframe.html

Comment: applied the code no reflection, we have trigger the anchor tag on onload, but i don't like the iframe, please check http://vkacademy.in/iframenew1.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirect to url like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
 window.location.href="https://youtu.be/701pwm78Q90";
});
```

Because some browsers blocks pop-ups automatically.

Comment: I did that ,but no reflection check the link  http://vkacademy.in/iframenew.html, please , we want to trigger the anchor tag on load,

Comment: Try updated answer because click() event is not triggering immediately when body loads

Comment: your answer is correct ,please check the same link. http://vkacademy.in/iframenew.html ,but how to do in jquery onload and triggering the anchor, because the iframe is used for external link like forms and videos , it takes time to load, that's i am looking in jquery,

Comment: ok i understand click is not triggering when body loads,but  we had an existing youtube videos from iframe link only, we take url link , without using iframe, is there is any  way to add videos in html, you tube also gives iframe only, i dont like to use iframe, since loading time is high

Comment: Try : `<embed src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/701pwm78Q90"> </embed>`

Comment: noted good idea , but any way in jquery onload and trigger click to anhor

Comment: Sorry, i think most of there is no way